# Problem in number theory using logarithms.

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

Question:-

If n is a natural number such than $n=p_1^{a_1}.p_2^{a_2}.p_3^{a_3}.......p_k^{a_k}$ and $p_1,p_2,...p_k$ are distinct primes, then show that $log(n)>=klog(2)$.

What I think is p1 is greater than or equal to 2. So is p2 and all the way to pn. So their product should be greater than and equal to $2^{k}$. Is this proof sufficient?

Source: *IIT JEE 1984*

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: Yes.It's right... If you write p_1  then iwith dollar signs you get $p_1$ which is better than $p1$. ... Click on Help at the top bar, choose the Help Center, choose the Q "How can I format mathematics here?"

Comment: @user254665 Thank you. i did check the post, but it had very few examples.

Comment: Did you go to the bottom line and click  on the MathJax quick reference?